# Vue JS - Access root computed property inside a component

Tags: vue.js

I'm attempting to access a computed property from the root Vue instance and access it inside a component. The `<p class="currency">` element which is output outside of the component template outputs {{ currency }} correctly, but when trying to access {{ currency }} inside of the component nothing is output. I have tried setting currency as a prop but this doesn't appear to make any difference. I'm sure there must be a way to access the root Vue instance from within the component, something like {{ vm.currency }} but again I have tried this to no avail.

Here is the HTML.

```
<div id="app">

  <ul class="plans">

    <plan-component : name="Basic" ></plan-component>

    <plan-component : name="Rec" ></plan-component>

    <plan-component : name="Team" ></plan-component>

    <plan-component : name="Club" ></plan-component>
  </ul>

  <template id="plan-component">
    <li>
      <h2 class="plan-name">{{ name }}</h2>
      <h3 class="plan-cost">{{ currency }}</h3>
    </li>
  </template>

  <p class="currency">{{ currency }}</p>

</div><!-- end #app -->
```

Here is the JS. The variable countryCode is defined elsewhere in my app, but like I said {{ currency }} is working outside of the component so this isn't an issue.

```
Vue.component('plan-component', {
  template: '#plan-component',

  props: {
    name: String,
  }
});

var vm = new Vue({
  el: '#app',

  computed: {
    currency: function() {
      if(countryCode === 'GB') {
        return "£";
      } else {
        return "$";
      }
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: where from countryCode is coming ?

Comment: It says this in the question: "The variable countryCode is defined elsewhere in my app, but like I said {{ currency }} is working outside of the component so this isn't an issue."

Answer (score 11, accepted):

For anyone with the same issue, you simply need to define $root before the property. So in my example instead of this...

```
<h3 class="plan-cost">{{ currency }}</h3>
```

...it needs to be this...

```
<h3 class="plan-cost">{{ $root.currency }}</h3>
```

The VueJS docs do talk about this under the [Parent Chain](https://vuejs.org/guide/components.html#Parent-Chain) section of Components.

Comment: You can also use vuex to do this

Comment: It's also possible to create a computed property: `computed: { currency() { return this.$root.currency } }` and then use it in HTML just as `{{ currency }}`.